# Getting Tagname value passed during execution in robot framework

Tags: robotframework

Need help in robot framework, I want to know how to pass tag names that passed during execution of robot file in robot framework to python function.

Example:
executing robot file with tag name Sanity, I want way to get the value Sanity and pass to the python function.
robot -i Sanity testsuite.robot

def pyfunction(tagname):
*** Here i need to get value "Sanity" which is passed during executing robot file.

Comment: What have you tried until now, and what was the result you got? Is your pyfunction called from the command line, or expected to be called from Robot Framework itself. With "pass(ed)" do you mean the value "Sanity" or the result of all the test cases with that tag name?

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I tried with -v Sanity and got value "Sanity" in python function. Its basically passing variable name instead of tagname.

Comment: Can you provide a complete [mcve] of your solution. You mention a few components, but not a single example that shows the complete chain of code from the command line, to your python function and back. This leaves us guessing what it __might__ be, which is not helpful.